# Python multithreading program is giving unexpected output

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I know that **there is no guarantee regarding the order of execution for the threads.** But my doubt is when I ran below code,

```
import threading

def doSomething():
    print("Hello ")

d = threading.Thread(target=doSomething, args=())
d.start()
print("done")
```

Output that is coming is either

```
Hello done
```

or this

```
Hello 
done
```

May be if I try too much then it might give me below as well

```
done
Hello
```

But I am not convinced with the first output. Since order can be different but how come both outputs are available in the same line. Does that means that one thread is messing up with other threads working?

Comment: That's very strange. I have run your code on my machine 1,000 times and the only output I get is

Hello
done
on separate lines. I wouldn't read too much in to it to be honest. It sounds like more of a problem with your interpreter that your code?

Comment: @H4KKR: Yeah, this would be super-sensitive to small differences in the interpreter, OS, whether the output is going to a terminal or a file, etc. To have a chance of reproducing, we'd need to know, at the least, OS, terminal/shell being used, and the Python interpreter and version. But it's ultimately not that interesting of a problem; `print` isn't atomic, so interleaving is legal. Either write from a single thread only, or synchronize across threads.

Comment: Thanks for valuable comments. I also think may be it is because of non atomic operation. But whenever I am running this, it is 50% giving me output is same line only. :-( 
Not sure if it is reproducible. In case you need. 
@ShadowRanger
Machine is Mac. OS is BigSur. Python version: Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) [Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
IDE: PyCharm.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic race condition. I can't personally reproduce it, and it would likely vary by interpreter implementation and the precise configuration applied to `stdout`. On Python interpreters without a GIL, there is basically no protection against races, and this behavior is expected to a certain extent. Python interpreters do tend to try to protect you from egregious data corruption due to threading, unlike C/C++, but even if they ensure every byte written ends up actually printed, they usually wouldn't try to make explicit guarantees against interleaving; `Hdelolnoe` would be a possible (if fairly unlikely given likely implementations) output when you're making no effort whatsoever to synchronize access to `stdout`.

On CPython, the GIL protects you more, and writing a single string to `stdout` is more likely to be atomic, but you're not writing a single string. Essentially, the implementation of `print` is to write objects one by one to the output file object as it goes, it doesn't batch up to a single string then call `write` just once. What this means is that:

```
print("Hello ")  # Implicitly outputs default end argument of '\n' after printing provided args
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
sys.stdout.write("Hello ")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

If the underlying stack of file objects that implements `sys.stdout` decides to engage in real I/O in response to the first `write`, they'll release the GIL before performing the actual write, allowing the main thread to catch up and potentially grab the GIL before the worker thread is given a chance to write the newline. The main thread then outputs the `done` and then the newlines from each `print` come out in some unspecified (and irrelevant) order based on further potential races.

Assuming you're on CPython, you could probably fix this by changing the code to this equivalent code using single `write` calls:

```
import threading
import sys

def doSomething():
    sys.stdout.write("Hello \n")

d = threading.Thread(target=doSomething)  # If it takes no arguments, no need to pass args
d.start()
sys.stdout.write("done\n")
```

and you'd be back to a race condition that only swaps the order, without interleaving (the language spec wouldn't guarantee a thing, but most reasonable implementations would be atomic for this case). If you want it to work with any guarantees without relying on the quirks of the implementation, you have to synchronize:

```
import threading

lck = threading.Lock()

def doSomething():
    with lck:
        print("Hello ")

d = threading.Thread(target=doSomething)
d.start()
with lck:
    print("done")
```